# Wiki Dump For All Titles In Mainspace Is Way More Than What Wikipedia Reported

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I am querying all revision histories for each wikipedia page. I downloaded wiki dump for list of page titles in main namespace from the link https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiktionary/20170320/
However, it seems like there are more than 12,000,000 titles from the dump I downloaded, which is way more than what wikipedia reported (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Size_comparisons). Can anyone tell me what is going on? Am I using the correct dump?

The reason I am asking is that it looks like it will take a few hundred days to get all revision histories if I query the history providing the article titles. So if there are any better ways to extract revision histories, it will be very helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that is a dump of pages in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page). Wikipedia's id is [`enwiki`](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20170820/), however even with the right dump making the counts match takes some efforts:

- Some pages are [redirects](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Redirects)
- Some pages aren't counted as valid content pages and thus are excluded from the [official statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Statistics). To be considered valid, a page should contain at least one internal link.